# How would I do this listing in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made this is Photoshop (http://i.imgur.com/pte5hfk.png - You cant see it there but there is separation lines in between text)in order to place it on my site however, I cannot get it to work properly. At the moment, I have just used `<img src = "" />` but it doesn't look good at all. Any Ideas?

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row"> the image is transparent too.
       <div class = "col-md-12" align = "center">
          <img class = "img-responsive" src = "img/sepline.png">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Ideas about what if you don't show us some code?! :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The only code I have to show you is the img src inside a container. It's not the placement that's wrong it's just the way it looks.

Comment: We don't know how it looks without code.  I assume that the image is transparent, however, I do not know what the color is behind the image.  Whether it "looks good" is subjective. Please give us more to work with!

Comment: <div class = "container">
  
   <div class = "row">
the image is transparent too.
    <div class = "col-md-12" align = "center">
    
     <img class = "img-responsive" src = "img/sepline.png">
    
    </div>
   
   </div>

Comment: @GANIZniz this time I'll do it for you, and I'll place the HTML in your question. Than go find your CSS and, click on the `|edit|` button and paste it beneath using the proper code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create a menu with HTML and CSS that looks like the image you posted, this should help you get started.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-custom">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item F</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-custom i.glyphicon {
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.nav-custom li {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.nav-custom li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
```

You might be able to accomplish the gradient dividers with WebKit CSS, but more likely you'd have to use images.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/natalieperna/g3cFk/1/